# Django ImageField upload works locally but not in production

Tags: python, django, imagefield

My models file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/',blank=True,default='avatars/no.png')
    genre = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, ("Homme")),
                                        (2, ("Femme")))
                                )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Locally when I fill the form, the image is saved in my folder `media/avatars/`.
But on heroku the image is not saved in this folder and therefore it can't be displayed.

Comment: How do you know it is not saved?

Comment: @DanielRoseman 
I have hosted my app on Heroku .... I've used the command heroku run bash -a appname  and cd to media/avatars and i'm not seeing any new file .But locally  , a new image is added to media/avatars

Comment: I guessed as much. You *cannot* store content on the filesystem in Heroku. Use somewhere permanent, such as S3.

Comment: Owh okay thank you so much. If I want to keep using heroku how can I insert images files into my postgresql database ?

Comment: As I said, save them on S3.

Comment: Ah, I just saw how S3 works. I really appreciate your help